# Will my 3g usb modem support any linux distro?

Tags: 14.04, 3g

I've used my 3g modem in kali linux running gnome.It works well. now I want to switch to Ubuntu/arch. Will it be suppoted on arch or ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu has a *try before installing* option so that you can check it out even before installing

Answer (score 0):

Get a USB stick, put Ubuntu (or another Live OS) on it, and boot into trial mode. Then, connect your 3g modem to see if it works. You don't have to blow away your current installation to find out if it's supported out of the box when there is a live OS available.